# How to create different users roles with permissions using azure active directory(without p1,p2 subscription)?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, adal, user-roles

**We are trying to implement user roles with permissions using an azure active directory without any p1 and p2 subscriptions**

If it is possible or not

Answer (score 0):

If you mean custom administrator roles, that's not possible without P1 or P2 licenses.

Comment: ok, so how I can create three roles like a customer, admin, and analyst using azure active directory..?

Comment: [Create and assign a custom role in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/roles-create-custom)